# Getting Error when executing the bin/setup-cluster command in Fredhopper installation?

Tags: 2013, smarttarget, fredhopper, linux

I am facing an error while executing bin/setup-cluster for a Fredhopper installation on a Linux box. Below is the detail for error:

`[fredhopper@domain fredhopper]$ grep "ERROR" data/log/agent.log data/instances/deployment/log/kitchen.log`

`data/instances/deployment/log/kitchen.log:ERROR 25-09 01:27:14,937 - Create Instance Staging - Creating instance 'dev' for installation 'FAS' with preset name '1' failed. Error 409 returned upon requesting resource 'http://domain:8177/instance/dev' with method 'PUT'.`

`data/instances/deployment/log/kitchen.log:ERROR 25-09 01:27:15,119 - Create Instance Live - Creating instance 'devlive' for installation 'FAS' with preset name '2' failed. Error 409 returned upon requesting resource 'http://domain:8177/instance/devlive' with method 'PUT'.`

`data/instances/deployment/log/kitchen.log:ERROR 25-09 01:27:15,120 - Create Instance Live - com.fredhopper.etl.jobs.control.core.DeploymentCoreException: Creating instance 'devlive' for installation 'FAS' with preset name '2' failed. Error 409 returned upon requesting resource 'http://domain:8177/instance/devlive' with method 'PUT'.`

Any guidance will be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP Code 409 is a conflict. When in response to a PUT, it would typically mean that something else is already in that location.

So in this context, it seems that you already have instances with preset 1 and 2 and so cannot create new ones with those presets. You should either delete the existing instances or chose different presets for 'dev' and 'devlive'.

Comment: I tried to stop and delete the instance with the following command but could not get succeed.
**bin\instance <INSTANCE> stop**
**bin\deployment-agent-client remove <INSTANCE>**
I have also tried by simply deleting the instances via WinSCP but again got the same error. 
Please provide some guidance on this.

Comment: You are on Linux, so you need to use forward-slashes. Backslashes are a Windows thing.